# How to run an Macro in PowerPoint in the edit mode without starting the presentation

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, powerpoint, ms-office

I have created a dropdown menu with a ComboBox and a small macro.
This dropdown menu only works when I switch to presentation mode.
However, I want to use the dropdown in the edit mode, as a template. Is there a simple way to do this.

I have already found some posts about this topic, but no real solution yet.

Comment: No,  Macros do not run in  Edit Mode.

Comment: Macros do run in edit mode, but it depends on how and where you created them - where are your macros stored and where is the dropdown located?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the ribbon UI instead. In that case your custom UI will be available in the edit mode. See [Customize the Office Fluent ribbon by using an Open XML formats file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file) for more information.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

You may also find the [Custom UI Editor](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm) helpful.